# How can I bind nested ViewModels from View to Controller in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, binding, viewmodel

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC 3 application in C# and I use Razor. I am now dealing with a problem concerning the binding of objects through ViewModels passed/received to/from the View by the Controller.
Let's make it clear. I have the following ViewModels:

```
public class ContainerViewModel
{
   public int ContainerId {get; set;}
   public string ContainerName {get; set;}
   public List<ItemPostModel> ItemData {get; set;}
}

public class ItemPostModel
{ 
   public int ItemId {get; set;}
   public string ItemName {get; set;}
   public int ItemValue {get; set;}
}
```

The **ContainerViewModel** is used to pass the data to the View. Its properties **ContainerId** and **ContainerName** are used just for display purposes. The **`List<ItemPostModel>`** property has to be filled using a **Form**. The View looks something like this (it is a simplified version):

```
<strong>@Model.ContainerName</strong>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <fieldset>
    @foreach(var item in Model.ItemData)
    {
       @Html.TextBox(item.ItemId);
       @Html.TextBox(item.ItemName);
       @Html.TextBox(item.ItemValue);

       <p>
           <input type="submit" value="Save" />
       </p>
    }
    </fieldset>
}
```

The **Controller** corresponding **action methods** are as follows:

```
public ActionResult UpdateItems()
{
   //fill in the ContainerViewModel lcontainer

   return View("UpdateItems", lcontainer);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItems(int containerId, ItemPostModel itemData)
{
   //store itemData into repository
}
```

The problem is that with this code the **ItemPostModel itemData** passed to the **Post ActionMethod UpdateItems** is always empty. The **containerId** is correctly passed. Same result if I use the following code in the Controller (obviously not DRY);

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItems(ContainerViewModel container)
{
   //extract itemData from ContainerViewModel container
   //store itemData into repository
}
```

How can I *"teach"* the application that I want the form elements stored in the **`List<ItemPostModel>`**? Shall I modify the **ModelBinder** or there is a simpler way to perform this task? Thanks everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Don't write loops in a view. Use editor templates:

```
<strong>@Model.ContainerName</strong>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ItemData)
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </fieldset>
}
```

and inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemPostModel.cshtml`):

```
@model ItemPostModel
@Html.TextBox(x => x.ItemId)
@Html.TextBox(x => x.ItemName)
@Html.TextBox(x => x.ItemValue)
```

And in the controller action you might need to specify the prefix:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateItems(
    int containerId, 
    [Bind(Prefix = "ItemData")]ItemPostModel itemData
)
{
   //store itemData into repository
}
```

and that should be pretty much all. The editor template will take care of generating the proper input field names for the binding to work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The **~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ItemPostModel.cshtml** is a partial view right? Moreover, why do you suggest not to use foreach in the View? Is it not to "spoil" the html with code nuggets? Thanks

Comment: @Francesco, yes the `ItemPostModel.cshtml` is a partial. ALso I suggest to avoid using loops in a view because there are editor templates which take care of generating proper names for the input fields. So not only that this simplifies the code but it works with the default model binder when you want to fetch those values back in the controller.

Comment: An important point that I initially missed that is worth highlighting - is that the EditorFor helper automatically handles the collection of ItemPostModel even though the EditorTemplate is for a single ItemPostModel (and not the collection).

Comment: It should be `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemId)` and not `@Html.TextBox(x => x.ItemId)`

Comment: [Bind(Prefix=Items)]... really helped me