# MVC dbContext find parent record when current record has no elements

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4.1, dbcontext

I'm a MVC/C# beginner so go easy.

I have an existing database where a Customer has zero or many Projects. I've built an ASP.Net project from ADODB Entity data model and dbContext code generators.

I have a customer: Joe Bloggs (ID=7). I click on the 'Projects' link for Joe Bloggs in my form to see his projects. He doesn't have any. I want to create a project for him so I call the Create action on the project controller.

I need to pass Joe Bloggs ID to the Create action for three reasons (which may not be necessary - please enlighten me if need be)

1. Because this is a project for Joe Bloggs I need to pass ID=7 into the controller so I can set the default Customer ID for him when generating the model data for the create view
2. When I hit the Cancel button on the Create view, I want to go back to the originally filtered view of projects based on Joe Blogs
3. When I hit save I want to got back to the originally filtered view of projects based on Joe Bloggs.

Anyway if I *do* have one or more projects for Joe Bloggs then I can use this monster below to access his id from the model data within the view:

```
<input type="button" title = "New Project" value="New Project" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", new { id = Model.First().Customer_ID })'" />
```

Here is the issue: if he doesn't have any projects, Model.First() doesn't return anything so I can't find the 'parent' Customer_ID record.

I used dbContext to generate the model classes (this is a data-first development). Something tells me I could extend these classes or create a new class to allow for the case above.

My current workaround is to use ViewBag to pass the various id's and strings from viewer > controller like a hot potato but this means if get three deep (Customer > Proejct > Task), and I want to display the customer name on the task, I've passed it twice. It smells.

I notice that the drop down in the Project Index view **has the Customer in it**. Here is my code for that:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Customer_ID", null, "Select a Customer to Filter", new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

I might be able to hack it out of there but really I want to be able to traverse up from a class which might be two or three deep and far removed from this drop down

Here is an abridged Customer and CustomerProject class generated from dbContext

```
public partial class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        this.CustomerProjects = new HashSet<CustomerProject>();
    }

    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public string Customer_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<CustomerProject> CustomerProjects { get; set; }
}

public partial class CustomerProject
{
    public CustomerProject()
    {
        this.Tasks = new HashSet<Task>();
        this.CustomerProjectTasks = new HashSet<CustomerProjectTask>();
    }

    public int CustomerProject_ID { get; set; }
    public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
    public string Project_Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<CustomerProjectTask> CustomerProjectTasks { get; set; }
}
```

I'm sure there is an obvious solution but my strength is in databases and VB6, not C#

At Mystere Man's suggestion I have built a ViewModel class, but I'm having a little trouble:

Here is what's in my model class file (as I understand it this is just a wrapper around the the existing project entity):

```
namespace zzz.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public class ProjectsViewModel
    {
        public int Customer_ID { get; set; }
        public ICollection<CustomerProject> CustomerProjects;
    }
}
```

Here's whats in the Index action of my controller (I havejust added my existing Project collection to the new ViewModel class):

```
    public ViewResult Index(int pCustomer_ID = 0, string pProjectName_Filter = "")
    {

        // Set up drop down
        ViewBag.Customer_ID = new SelectList(db.Customers.OrderBy(x => x.Customer_Name), "Customer_ID", "Customer_Name");
        //ViewBag.Selected_Customer_ID = Customer_ID;

        // If no parameters entered, show nothing
        // Otherwise optionally filter each parameter
        var projects = from p in db.CustomerProjects
            orderby p.Active, p.Project_Order
            where
            (p.Project_Name.Contains(pProjectName_Filter) || pProjectName_Filter.Equals("")) &&
            (p.Customer_ID == pCustomer_ID || pCustomer_ID.Equals(0)) &&
            !(pCustomer_ID.Equals(0) && pProjectName_Filter.Equals(""))
            select p;


        var customerprojects = new ProjectsViewModel
        {
            Customer_ID = pCustomer_ID,
            CustomerProjects = projects.ToList()
        };


        return View(customerprojects);
    }
```

Here's an extract from my view (I have tried to iterate through the Project collection within the ViewModel class):

```
@model IEnumerable<BistechPortal.Models.ProjectsViewModel>

<table>
@foreach (var item in Model.CustomerProjects)
{
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Project_Name)
    </td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

When I run the Index action, on the foreach line I get:

```
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<zzzzPortal.Models.ProjectsViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'CustomerProjects' "
```

Please translate - why can't it find my 'CustomerProjects' collection inside my ViewModel?

Comment: As I understand, your Model is of type `Customer`, so you want to have `<input type="button" title = "New Project" value="New Project" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Create", new { id = Model.Customer_ID })'" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is why you should not pass entity objects directly to the view.  In most cases, the view needs more information (or different information) than what the defined entity provides.

This is why View Models exist.  You would create a View Model that contains the Customer_ID and the Projects (and any other data you need).  Then, you can access the Customer_ID even if the user has no projects.

```
public class ProjectsViewModel {
     public int Customer_ID {get;set;}
     public List<CustomerProject> CustomerProjects;
}
```

Then you pass this new object to your view.

*(added by the OP:)*

To pass this object to your view you need to tell the view that it is no longer accepting data of type CustomerProjects, **and** (this took me three hours to work out) that it is no longer getting 'enumerable' data.

So in your view change

```
@model IEnumerable<Portal.Models.CustomerProjects>
```

to

```
@model Portal.Models.ProjectsViewModel
```

Also in your view you now want to iterate over Model.CustomerProject, so change

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

to

```
@foreach (var item in Model.CustomerProjects)
```

Comment: OK I've had a crack at creating a View Model but being an amatuer I'd appreciate any assistance you could give in building one. I have added some info to my original question.

Comment: and thinking about it perhaps I should add the entire Customer class to the view method (as I want the name also). However that doesn't seem right because everytime I fill the new class up with data I'll have two copies of the Customer class - the one in the underlying Projects class, and one in the wrapper mode view class.

Another 'design' direction is to alter the way the Project class  is populated so that there is always at least one dummy 'element' even when there is no data, so I can get to the parent. Seems like a hack but I'd like any comments on this.

Comment: and while I am creeping the scope of the question, should I put my Customer Select list into this model view also? Just trying to explore the exact purpose of this layer. If it is pure data used by a specific view then it would seem that the modelview's purpose is to define a data structure which will be used by the view, and the controllers purpose is to populate it.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - That's correct.  The View Model's purpose is to provide a model that is specific to the views requirements.  Only very simplistic applications can get away with using the same model for both view and data.  In most cases, the views requirements are different from the data models requirements.  More info http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. Actually I was just reading that particular link. Any idea about my error? - why is 'CustomerProjects' not visible in my ProjectsViewModel class, and what is the correct syntax to iterate over the CustomerProjects collection within the view model?

I hope it's only syntax that I'm struggling with here. Any suggestions welcome. I am having difficulty finding end to end sample code for a view model which contains a collection of a class that is an entity.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - your error is because your model is of type IEnumerable<CustomerProject>, and the IEnumerable interface does not have a member or property by the name of CustomerProjects.  Instead of `foreach(var item in Model.CustomerProjects)` just use `foreach(var item in Model)`, but you should really be using Display and EditorTemplates instead of foreach.

Comment: Thanks. I realise I should be using templates but one thing at a time! 
    foreach(var item in Model) 

was my first try but then this expression fails: 

    item.EntityActive

Entity active is inside the CustomerProject class, which is inside the ProjectsViewModel class. So what syntax do I use to access it?

Also as far as I can tell there is only one 'member' in ProjectsViewModel and there should be many 'members' within CustomerProjects inside that, so I need to iterate through CustomerProjects _inside_ ProjectsViewModel

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700558/how-can-i-bind-nested-viewmodels-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc3) implies that if I define CustomerProjects of type _List_ in my View Model then I can use _forach(var item in Model.CustomerProject)_ . Whether thats correct or not. Anyway I gave it a go and same error. What I don't understand is that in the Controller I **can** set the _CustomerProjects_ member in the ProjectsViewModel. If its just a matter of the type stopping me, exactly what do I need to define it as in the View Model for it to work?

Comment: In my view, _@forach(var item in Model)_ followed by _modelitem => item.Customer_ID_ runs without error. I notice that if try debugging _@foreach(var item in customerprojects_ in my controller, there are never any items. If I look at the locals I can see a number of _CustomerProjects_ inside my ViewModel class. So what do I have to add to make CustomerProjects visible or have the correct type so that I can iterate through it in my view? Call me a dinosuar but it was never this difficult in VB6.

Comment: Ok I've now seen a number of examples where the View Model class has a property of type List or IEnumerable against another class, along with the syntax _@foreach (var item in Model.CustomerProjects)_ . Even though that is not best practice, I want to know why this isn't working for me. So I think the problem is not in the view syntax. I am unable to debug the view so I can't see what the data looks like, but when it's going in from the controller it definitely has a _CustomerProjects_ property.
_

Comment: So after much hunting around, in my view page I changed _@model IEnumerable<Portal.Models.ProjectsViewModel>_ to _@model Portal.Models.ProjectsViewModel_ . With my perfect hindsight I can see that my controller is not passing in data that is enumerable so it makes sense. In my defense, I am building this from the various code generators and this is a line I have not yet studied in much detail.

Comment: I have added detail to your answer and accepted it. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.