# EditorFor isn't using EditorTemplate in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, editorfor

I'v been bashing my head against a wall trying to get EditorFor working as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5700558/how-can-i-bind-nested-viewmodels-from-view-to-controller-in-mvc3), but I can't for the life of me get my version to work.

I have two ViewModels:

**InterviewViewModel**

```
public class InterviewViewModel
{
    ...
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

and **QuestionViewModel**:

```
public class QuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I have tried creating EditorTemplates in two places,

> /Views/Interview/EditorTemplates/QuestionViewModel.cshtml

and

> /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/QuestionViewModel.cshtml

Neither one appears to do anything.

### Controller code:

```
public ActionResult MyClass(int id = 0)
    {
        using (RRContext db = new RRContext())
        {
            ...

            List<QuestionModel> questionModels = new List<QuestionModel>();
            questionModels = db.QuestionModels.ToList();

            ...

            viewModel.Questions = questionViewModels;

        return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

### My View contains:

```
@model ResidentRank.Models.Interview.InterviewViewModel

... (html.beginform is here)
Html.EditorFor(model => model.Questions);
```

### EditorTemplate code:

```
@model ResidentRank.Models.Interview.QuestionViewModel
<div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0px;">
  <label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.QuestionName)</label>
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuestionOption, Model.OptionSelector)
</div>
```

The question banging around in my head is "WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?!"

Comment: What do you mean by "WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?!" What's the actual error you getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error; that's actual text in the view that I added when nothing was showing up.  The idea was that if I had some other logic on the page causing the div below it not to show, then that text would.

Comment: Actually it works for me. I will publish my solution soon.

Comment: This should work, and as Raj shows, it works for him.  That means you have something in the code you are NOT showing us that is likely interfering with things.  I suggest you start simplifying your code until you can get a COMPLETE sample that you can post that still has problems for you (not a sample that you edit out things, like you have done here).  Chances are, while simplifying, you will find it suddenly works.  Then you need to backtrack and figure out what you removed.

Comment: In the editor template you have QuestionViewModel but in controller the questionModels = db.QuestionModels.ToList();
            ...
            viewModel.Questions = questionViewModels; is a list. so it wont use the template

Comment: Actually EditorFor is automatically supposed to use the list, as long as everything is named properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HomeController

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Display(int id = 0)
    {
        var questionViewModel = new InterviewViewModel {
            Questions =
                new List<QuestionViewModel>()
                {
                    //Hard coded values to represent data coming from db i.e db.QuestionModels.ToList();
                    new QuestionViewModel() {QuestionId = 1, QuestionName = "A"},
                    new QuestionViewModel() {QuestionId = 2, QuestionName = "B"}
                }
        };

        return View(questionViewModel);
    }
```

ViewModels

```
  public class InterviewViewModel {
    public List<QuestionViewModel> Questions { get; set; }
  }

  public class QuestionViewModel {
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionName { get; set; }
  }
```

\Views\Home\Display.cshtml

```
  @model MvcApplication1.Models.Interview.InterviewViewModel

  @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
  {
      <fieldset>
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Questions)
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />
      </fieldset>
  }
```

\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\QuestionViewModel.cshtml

Make sure this is a partial view.

```
  @model MvcApplication1.Models.Questions.QuestionViewModel
  <div style="clear:both; margin:10px 0px;">
     <label>@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.QuestionName)</label>
  </div>
```

Note that I removed the

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedQuestionOption, Model.OptionSelector)
```

for to keep the view simple.

This displays..

[image]

Comment: I was able to get an overly simplified version to work.  Still working on getting one with actual data in it to behave properly.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: The issue was that I was declaring Html.EditorFor without a "@" immediately inside the Html.BeginForm element.  I was thinking it was in 'code-mode' at that point with the opening bracket...apparently not.  Adding an @ and wrapping it in a fieldset fixed the problem.